# calculate the length of the path to find maximum value in binary search tree

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

how can i find the length of the path that we used to find the maximum value in binary search tree (like form A====>B one step and A====>B====>C three steps)
and here's my code to find the maximum value and i have tried every solution in her but i didn't find an answer

```
public int findMax(){
        if(root == null){ // check if the root is not empty 
            return 0;
        }
        Node current = root;
        while(current.rightChild != null){
        current =current.rightChild ;
    }
        return current.value ;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the length of the path from root to the largest value, just keep a counter and increment it in the while loop, so that every time you traverse to the next node, the counter increases by one.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
class Holder {
    int length;
}

public int findMax(Holder holder) {
    Node current = root;
    Node result = null;
    while (current != null) {
        result = current;
        current = current.rightChild;
        if (current != null) {
            holder.length++;
        }
    }

    return result.value;
}
```

`Holder.length` should hold the length on return.

Answer (score 0):

A binary tree is not guaranteed to be balanced, so you need to look at left and right children.  Nicely recusive, something like this:

```
public int findMax (Node root) {
   return findMaxWork (root, 0);
}

public int findMaxWork (Node node, int level) {

  int leftMax = level;
  if (node.left != null) leftMax = findMaxWork (node.left, level + 1);
  int rightMax = level;
  if (node.right != null) rightMax = findMaxWork (node.right, level + 1);
  return Math.max(leftMax, rightMax);
}
```